# Can I concatenate the result of two helper methods in single erb output

Tags: ruby, sinatra, erb

I created a helper to output some text using erb

```
<%= helper_method %>
```

but if i tried to put it 2 times it will not work ..for eg..

```
<% =  
helper_method  
helper_method  
%>
```

I am expecting the text twice...but I get only once...

Comment: Because last returned value included.

Comment: thank you guys for the answers.. the intent was more of a continous coding in erb..say you call method to output some after that I don't want start another <%= to output another...one...so for every different output I need to tag the <%= ...not sure if there are better ways to do it

Comment: `<%= [meth1, meth2, meth3].join %>` if you must, but you seem to be looking hard for something it was never meant to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like

```
<%= %Q(#{helper_method} #{helper_method}) %>
```

Answer (score 4):

Each `<%= %>` outputs a single string, so either join them in a single string, or do it twice.

```
<%= helper_method %> (or <%= ... -%> )
<%= helper_method %>
```

There are a variety of ways to concatenate; `%Q`, normal string interpolation, etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= helper_method + helper_method %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to print a String multiple times(the string in your case comes from a helper), you can simply use the multiplier operator

```
#helper
def helper_method
  "Text"
end

#view
<%= helper_method * 2 %>
```

The result in a new string like this: TextText

HTH

Answer (score -1):

When you say `<%= helper_method %>`, `=` means print the output, but when you say

```
<% =  
helper_method1  
helper_method2 
%>
```

Rails doesn't know which out put should print, because it has two methods:

- helper_method1
- helper_method2

Comment: It's not that it "doesn't know" which to print. It's just that `<%= ... %>` in Erb only calls `to_s` on the last expression in the block. (And as tagged, this is Sinatra, not Rails.)

Comment: @Phrogz well, it's been changed to Rails now :)

Comment: @RocketR Huh. That seems like a bad edit. I've reverted it :)